# Foreach loop in Latex gives error "undefined control sequence"

Tags: foreach

I checked multiple times how to write a foreach loop in Lualatex with PDF output but I simply do not get it to work. Here is a simple example with a complete document

```
\documentclass[paper=152.4 mm:228.6 mm,fontsize=11 pt, twoside]{scrbook} 

\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {1,...,7}
Test \i;

Test
\end{document}
```

The Test is printed correctly when I comment out the loop. The loop leads to the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.4 \foreach
           \i in {1,...,7}
```

Comment: I believe `\foreach` requires the `pgffor` package.

Comment: Correct. Add \usepackage{pgffor} before \begin{document}

Comment: @scs LuaLaTeX isn't really related to your question, that's a PGF/TikZ issue instead

Comment: @JairoA.delRio It's not even a PGF/TikZ issue, but an issue of not loading the package at all.

Comment: There is no `foreach` loop in Lua.

Comment: Works with 2 nested foreach loops to autogenerate a book of 200 pages.

Comment: Title and tags corrected

Comment: @Campa: I will post the answer. If you post also I will delete it

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to add   **\usepackage{pgffor}**  before **\begin{document}**.

```
\documentclass[paper=152.4 mm:228.6 mm,fontsize=11 pt, twoside]{scrbook} 

\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}

\foreach \j in {1,...,7}{
Test \j}

\end{document}
```

The solution works for nested loops also:

```
\documentclass[paper=152.4 mm:228.6 mm,fontsize=11 pt, twoside]{scrbook} 

\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}

\foreach \i in {1,...,9}{
  \foreach \j in {1,...,7}{
  Test \j}
}

Test
\end{document}
```

The foreach loop can be integrated into large documents. This was tested to generate a book with 200 pages by autorepeating 3 pages in the inner loop and adding one additional page in the outer loop